# Android Google Maps with Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I created a new Blank Activity with fragment in Android Studio and I need to include Google Map using SupportMapFragment. On the top of the layout, I want to keep the toolbar, which shows the activity name by default. How to do it or is there any tutorial?

Comment: Along with the Blank Activity template, there's a Google Maps Activity template, have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a tutorial explaining it well here:
http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-supportmapfragment-example/

But to to keep the toolbar just add this in your xml activity (not as tutorials says), instead of modifying it completely, as you may have your toolbar defined in your xml, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

On the tools:context add your activity class name with a preceding . (dot).

Adjust the width and height of the relative layout to match your needs. E.g. 200dp or leave them match_parent.

If you need any more help let me know.

Comment: is MainActivity not the same class as SupportMapFragmentActivity on the tutorial? If so, could you explain what should I do in the MainActivity?

Comment: Yes it can be the same as the tutorial. It should be the activity class in which you want to display the map. Just follow the tutorial and you should be good to go.

But if you have already an xml file with customized toolbars and stuff, then you should just add the above xml portion and not replace your entire xml as in the tutorial.